# Multi variable for loop Java Script

Tags: javascript

Is there any way, below code works properly..
i want 'i' to stop when the limit is reached .. without using an if condition

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < a1.length, j < a2.length; i++, j++) {
  console.log('a1: ' + '[' + i + ']' + a1[i]);
  console.log('a2: ' + a2[j]);
}
```

Comment: is there any special reason for using two counters with the same content?

Comment: No special reasons,other than am lazy

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of a loop should be a boolean condition.

This one

```
i < a1.length, j < a2.length
```

is actually interpreted in such way that it returns the result of `i < a1.length` only.

Since you want the loop to execute while **both** of conditions are true, combine these conditions using logical AND operator:

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < a1.length && j < a2.length; i++, j++) {
  console.log('a1: ' + '[' + i + ']' + a1[i]);
  console.log('a2: ' + a2[j]);
}
```

By the way, `i` and `j` are actually duplicating each other. You may use the single loop counter:

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length && i < a2.length; i++) {
  console.log('a1: ' + '[' + i + ']' + a1[i]);
  console.log('a2: ' + a2[i]);
}
```

or even

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var minLength = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length);

for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
  console.log('a1: ' + '[' + i + ']' + a1[i]);
  console.log('a2: ' + a2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thing is ,i need ' j ' to go till 10

Comment: @CodeBean There is no convenient and proper way to do this using `for` loop without `if` condition. Moreover, there is not so much sense. However, you may implement it using `while`.

Answer (score 0):

no need for if condition

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < a1.length, j < a2.length, a1[i]; i++, j++) {
  console.log('a1: ' + '[' + i + ']' + a1[i]);
  console.log('a2: ' + a2[j]);
}
```